# Oracle equivalent of suser_name() used in SQL Server

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the Oracle equivalent of suser_name() used in SQL Server

Comment: And what does `suser_name()` do or return?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
Please refer the above link.

Comment: Please refer to this link for the answer: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Functions.html#GUID-D079EFD3-C683-441F-977E-2C9503089982

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly they use [***`SYS_CONTEXT`***](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm) for tracking and auditing purposes like the one below :

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') 
   FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

we can get the login identification name of the user  by using `SUSER_NAME ( [ server_user_id ] )` on SQL Server

try Use the `FND_USER` table on oracle .
use sif you have the Server_user_id